# Proof of Relation between Integral and Hypergeometric Function

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, hypergeometric-function

By using a mathematical software I was able to deduce that the integral:
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{t}\frac{ds}{\left[\left( 1-s^p \right)^{p-1}\right]^{1/p}}
\end{equation}
where $p>1$, can be expressed in the following way:
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{t}\frac{ds}{\left[\left( 1-s^p \right)^{p-1}\right]^{1/p}}=_{2}F_{1}\left( 1-\frac{1}{p},\frac{1}{p},1+\frac{1}{p};t^p \right)t
\end{equation}
where $_{2}F_{1}\left( \alpha,\beta,\gamma;z \right)$ is the ordinary hypergeometric Gauss function:
\begin{equation}
_{2}F_{1}\left( \alpha,\beta,\gamma;z \right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\alpha)_n(\beta)_n}{(\gamma)_n}\frac{z^n}{n!}
\end{equation}
with $()_n$ to be the rising [*Pochhammer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol) symbol. The issue is that I am new to the hypergeometric functions theory and not yet good with this kind of manipulations. Therefore, I am not able to prove analytically that this relation above holds.
I tried to go throught the definition of the [*Incomplete Beta function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function) but it does not always hold that $s>0$.

I would really appreciate some help, at least where to start from. Thank you.

Comment: I assume that by the Pochhammer symbol, for this context, you mean rising factorial, right?

Comment: @Masacroso Correct.

Comment: Take a look at [this paper](https://homepage.tudelft.nl/11r49/documents/wi4006/hyper.pdf), it have a proof for a integral representation of the hypergeometric function $_2F_1$

Comment: Expand the Integrand into a series using the generalized binary formula, then integrate each term of the series, and compare the result with the definition of the hypergeometric function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider

$$\int^t_0 (1-s^p)^{\frac{1}{p}-1}\,ds$$

Let $s^p = x t^p $ hence $dx = \frac{t}{p} x^{1/p-1}$

$$\frac{t}{p}\int^1_0 x^{1/p-1}(1-t^px)^{\frac{1}{p}-1}\,dx$$

Now use the integral representation

$$\tag{1}\beta(c-b,b) \, _2F_1(a,b;c;z)=\int_0^1 \frac{x^{b-1}(1-x)^{c-b-1}}{(1-xz)^a}\, dx$$

With $b=1/p,c=1+\frac{1}{p},a=1-\frac{1}{p},z = t^p$

$$t\int^1_0 x^{1/p-1}(1-t^px^p)^{\frac{1}{p}-1}\,dx=\frac{t}{p}\beta\left(1,\frac{1}{p}\right) \, _2F_1\left(1-\frac{1}{p},\frac{1}{p};1+\frac{1}{p};t^p\right)$$

Note that

$$\frac{1}{p}\beta\left(1,\frac{1}{p}\right) = \frac{\Gamma(1)\Gamma(1/p)}{p\Gamma(1+1/p)} = 1$$

For the proof (1) http://advancedintegrals.com/2017/01/integral-representation-of-gauss-hypergeometric-function-proof/

Comment: I have verified it and it is correct. Thank you for taking the time to provide a proof. Also, thank you for the link.